# Searching my sql database is not working, it is bringing back all of the results

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a SQL table that has 3 columns: `client_id`, `domains` and `comment`. On my PHP page I have some text boxes that allow the user to search for a specific client ID or domain from within the table. However when searching it brought back every result in the table not just the results that had a `client_id` 78 for example.

I tried hard-coding the value into the statement, like so:

```php
$sql = "SELECT client_id, domain, comment FROM FirstAttempt WHERE client_id = '78' OR domain = 'sausage'";
```

This works fine.

My question is; how can I edit that line of code so that it searches for whatever is inputted into the text boxes?

My full code is below..

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Dylanc";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "FirstAttempt";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

$sql = "SELECT client_id, domain, comment FROM FirstAttempt WHERE client_id = '78' OR domain = 'sausage'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Client ID: " . $row["client_id"]. " - Domain: " . $row["domain"]. "Comments:" . $row["comment"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

And the form that uses that php is this...

```html
<form action="Search-Call.php" name="FirstAttempt" method="POST">
    <font face="impact" color="white">Client ID:</font>
    <input type="text" name="client_id" ><br>
    <br>
    <font face="impact"color="white">Domain:</font>
    <input type="text" name="domain"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to search for the database-entries, which have client_id 78 and the domain 'sausage' ? Then you should change your query to WHERE client_id = '78' AND domain = 'sausage'. But in fact, it is not very clear, what you want to archive.

Comment: I want to be able to enter a value into the text box on the form and then when i click submit it searches the database for entries and returns back any results. However every time i clicked submit it brought back every result that was in the table. So i actually defined the client id as 78 to see if that brought back just results that have client id 78 and it did. So basically, i need to know how to make FirstAttempt WHERE client_id = '78' OR domain = 'sausage'" equal what is in the text boxes rather than have to define them

Comment: For the short term, just try doing:

`$sql = "SELECT client_id, domain, comment FROM FirstAttempt WHERE client_id = '" . $_POST['client_id']. "' OR domain = '" . $_POST['domain']"'";`

However - this is actually bad practice and opens you up to all sorts of issues (SQL Injection), so once you figure out how to get your query to work, you should look into using [Prepared Statements](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection) in order to protect your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace this line of code:

```
$sql = "SELECT client_id, domain, comment FROM FirstAttempt WHERE client_id = '78' OR domain = 'sausage'";
```

By this:

```
$client_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['client_id']);
$domain    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['domain']);
$sql       = "SELECT client_id, domain, comment FROM FirstAttempt WHERE client_id = '$client_id' OR domain = '$domain'";
```

Of course you might want to add some more validation code (over $client_id and $domain variables) before building your SQL query.